# How to see if the user click inside something?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys i have a little problem.

I have a page something like this:

```
<div id="the_box"><iframe src="somesite"></iframe></div>
```

I have the div on my page but inside the iframe theres a form from another site where i would like to know when the user clicked a button inside that frame, is there a easy way to register that a user clicked?

Comment: Do you have control over the other site?

Comment: if second(remote) website is yours then you can do this otherwise NOT.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible due to browser security restrictions. Events are not allowed to propagate over `iframe` elements whose `src` attribute is an external domain.

Answer (score 0):

No this cannot be done . Maximum you can know is when the user clicks anywhere on the iFrame. Not on any elements inside the IFrame , as that violates the browser rules and Internet protocols .